# Session variable throw nullreference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, session-variables

I have a web application using ASP MVC4

I set my session variable in

```
protected void Session_Start()
    {
        Session["__UserLanguage"] = "EN";
    }
```

And I use it on my controller

```
private void AddTranslation()
{
   string language = Request.Form["Language"];
   if (language != null)
   {
       Session["__UserLanguage"] = language;
   }
   else
   {
       language = Session["__UserLanguage"] as string;
   }
}
```

but when i publish it on IIS it return

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

when I try to get it in my controller

```
Session["__UserLanguage"] = language;
```

Why ? :'(

**EDIT :** In fact After debugging Session_Start() was not used in my application ... How that's possible ?

**EDIT 2 :** after adding

```
<remove name="Session" />
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition=""  />
```

This resolve my problem ! Why that's not directly added by visual studio :(

Comment: 1) Is Session enabled on that production application?  2) Application restarts will flush in-process session.  Your code has to be able to handle that.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: 1)Yeap Session State was enabled in IIS with a 30 min timeout. 2) Normaly "Session_Start()" will allways put "EN" in Session["__UserLanguage"]!

Comment: About how to use this site: do not add answers inside the question, post a self-answer.

Comment: @HugoB. Adding -resolved- to the tile is not considered as a good practice - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question. If you have found a solution, then you can post it as an answer for your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after adding

```
<remove name="Session" />
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition=""  />
```

This resolve my problem!